# Как правильно прописывать пути в Angular 2?

Tags: angular2, meteor

У меня проблема, я никак не могу добиться нормальной работы путей в Angular 2. Может ктото сталкивался\знает как лучше сделать?

Файл main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from './app.routes'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Файл app.routes.ts

```
import {

RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import {
    HelloComponent
} from './imports/index'

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: HelloComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Файл app.component.html:

```
<div>
    <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

И, наконец, суть ошибки. Дом рендерится вобще неправильно, привожу код:

```
<my-app><div> <app-nav-bar _nghost-ile-2=""><ul _ngcontent-ile-2=""> <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: left;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-href="/" href="/">Home</a> </li><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: left;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-href="/index/books" href="/index/books">Books</a> </li><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: right;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="active" ng-reflect-href="/index/about" href="/index/about">About</a> </li><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: right;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-href="/" href="/">Login</a> </li> </ul> </app-nav-bar> <router-outlet></router-outlet><app-hello _nghost-ile-4="">
<html _ngcontent-ile-4="">
<head _ngcontent-ile-4="">
  <link _ngcontent-ile-4="" class="__meteor-css__" href="/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=d42394b95cde74014bba42c21ff2737c29b8fc61" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <base _ngcontent-ile-4="" href="/">
</head>
<body _ngcontent-ile-4="">
  <my-app _ngcontent-ile-4="">Loading....</my-app>
</body>
</html>
</app-hello> </div> </my-app>
```

Я так понял, на месте app-hello почемуто рендерится my-app и так по кругу, я не пойму почему =(

Comment: index.html, и описание AppComponent (импортировали ли директивы)? Также с инитом роутера надо выставить стратегию ссылок.

Comment: Проблема исчезла сама (вот бы всегда так!) магическим образом. Но всетаки, я перезаписал все файлы, пересоздал базу (все это с выключеным серваком, естественно). Я не знаю почему, но тот же код заработал как надо и появилась проблема №2, о которой я спрошу позже =)

Comment: Возможно проблема решилась сама из-за кеша, ангуляр надолго кеширует все свои шаблоны

Comment: При разработке была использована дев версия, так что врядли.